# indexing a directory constantly changing lucene

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I have created an index using the file system and so far it has indexed all the files in the directory that I pointed at. The thing here is that, at the moment, the directory has only 45 file and those 45 files have been indexed. Now, the directory is constantly getting text files inside of it, I want to index this directory in such a way that it indexes only the new files that came in, rather than indexing the whole directory again and again every time a file comes in. How would I achieve this?

Comment: There isn't really any need to rewrite your whole index when adding a document.  I'm not sure I understand where this problem is coming from.  Perhaps some details on how you are building the index would be helpful?

Comment: I want to automate the process of indexing on that specific directory, by running a cron-job that runs every 1 hour ... this, i think, will run the code that i wrote for the indexing from the beginning which will run the function again hence causing the index to be re-built ... am i right?

Comment: Sure.  Well, probably.  Would depend on your implementation.  Your implementation could be was designed to open an existing index if it exists, keep track of what files it had already indexed, then look for new ones and just add those as new documents, for all I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) which will tell you when new files appear in the folder.

This, however, isn't much useful if your app is offline and new files appear during that period. To address this, you can add a separate field in Lucene and query the index before indexing any new file to check if that file exists.

Comment: The program i wrote, that generate the txt files in the directory, runs every hour ... and did think of using `WatchServices` but i thought there could be another way

Comment: This seems like a good solution, marking as answer, thank you

Comment: Nice! Do you query the index before adding a file?

Comment: No, why? .. What i did was that i ran an infinite loop that looks over the directory at all times ... and when the files start getting generated it takes the path of the file and indexes it